# How to increase my intelligence, experience and knowledge?

Tags: meaning

I don't know where to start? I rush a lot.

On Google I searched how to gain knowledge and clicked on five types of books that **"Increase Intelligence"**.

- Science
- Philosophy
- Serious Fiction
- History
- Poetry & Resources

also politics. *[{JonMarkPerry} - making six!]*

I have a long way to go to improve, step by step, but I rush and think that there is no point.

> I want to be with learned people. I want to be able to ask questions and learn from them. I must be enthusiastic to do this. I read as many books as I can; I search on the internet for the best websites that can give you good knowledge. Meet experienced people and talk to them - that is the best way to gain knowledge.

But I don't want to tell that I don't know much. I have learning difficulties and always make mistakes. In school I didn't have the confidence to talk to people - mostly girls - I never talked and was shy, too.

But I have learned my mistake at the age of 20. I didn't know about what other people do, I just use to think about myself.

I want to know is this right above or can you give me more advice. I just talk simple and don't talk much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to the English language.

Comment: Hi. Do you have a question about the English language?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are describing **[introversion](https://www.psychologytoday.com/basics/introversion)**.

This is not a permanent condition and can be cured. Making small progressions at first will increase your confidence, and allow you more freedom in social relationships.

But don't try too hard, because you will go off the personality scale at the other end - **[extroversion](https://www.psychologytoday.com/basics/extroversion)**, which can prove to be equally irritating to both you and others.

In-between lies the happy medium of being a **[socialite](http://www.socialitelife.com/)**, and this is where you will have the most fun.

Good luck, I wish you the best!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I could not disagree more. The term the OP is describing is shyness, "the feeling of apprehension, lack of comfort, or awkwardness especially when a person is in proximity to other people." Introversion is "the state of or tendency toward being wholly or predominantly concerned with and interested in one's own mental life" This is not a negative thing, and this does not need to be cured. Extraversion is "the act, state, or habit of being predominantly concerned with obtaining gratification from what is outside the self" this is also not a negative thing.

Comment: Also, a "Socialite" has nothing to do with being comfortable around other people. Wikipedia says: A socialite is a person who has a reputation in upper class society for spending a significant amount of time participating in social activities such as parties, charity and fine arts fundraisers, and other fashionable events."

Comment: I agree with @DJMcMayhem - I'm introverted, but I'm not shy nor am I in any need of being cured. Likewise some of my friends are extroverts and I enjoy their company and wouldn't want them cured of their extroversion. I find socialites extremely irritating because they are far too concerned with being at the right places, at the right times, wearing the right clothes, in the company of the right people.